# Update custom control field on data updated in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, angularjs, mapcontrol

I have some snippets down there, I need to update a specific field according to subscription data but when I call my `createControl` function it renders new control not updating

here is create control function:

```
this.createLeftControl = function(template, scope, options, isUpdate) {
            const defaultOptions = {
                position: "topleft"
            };
            let container;
            options = _.extend(defaultOptions, options);
            const ControlContainer = L.Control.extend({
                options,
                onAdd() {
                    container = $compile(template)(scope);
                    return container[0];
                }
            });
            this.instance.addControl(new ControlContainer());
            return container;
        };
```

And this is subscription function I added extra parameter `isUpdate` for check in `onAdd` function and tried something but it didn't work

```
legendExtensionSubscription.subscribe(data => {
            this.activePluginsCount = data.length;
            let template = `
        <div class="active-modules-container">
        <h3>Active modules : ${this.activePluginsCount}</h3>
        </div>`;
            this.$scope.map.createLeftControl(
                template,
                this.$scope,
                {
                    position: "bottomleft"
                },
                true
            );
        });
```

Edit :
`$scope` and `$compile` from angular but i think it's not related to my issue. Main problem is when data changes `createControl` function renders another container on top of that but i want to have a single container which content changes depending on the number of active plugins , im still noob  leaflet and just i need onUpdate function or something like that.

Screenshot :

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Which data in the control changes? Also, you initially define control position as `topleft`, but later you have `botomleft`. Is control supposed to change position or is this another control?

Comment: the activePluginsCount is changing and data is array and i took the length for display count on screen also i edited and added screenshot and in screenshot as you can see there is 2 control exist i want only one control and update value related to activePluginsCount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm not familiar with Angular, answer will be based on vanilla JS.

All you have to do is to add some custom method to the control, let's say will be `updateContent`, where you set/update content of the control. Control definition (based on official Leaflet example) could then look something like this:

```
L.Control.Watermark = L.Control.extend({
  control: null,      
  onAdd: function(map) {
    var div = L.DomUtil.create('div');   
    div.style = 'background-color: white; border: 1px gray solid; padding: 1px 4px;'
    div.innerHTML = 'Custom control content';   
    return div;
  },        
  onRemove: function(map) {
  },
  updateContent: function(newContent) {
    this.getContainer().innerHTML = newContent;
  }
});

L.control.watermark = function(opts) {
  return new L.Control.Watermark(opts);
}
```

If you then create your map control with

```
var myControl = L.control.watermark({ position: 'bottomleft' }).addTo(map);
```

you can later change control content with simple call:

```
myControl.updateContent('New control content');
```

Comment: Nice one this one works too and i implemented angular way solution aswell. Have a nice day.